# how would you retrieve cacti data remotely

Tags: cacti

I have a cacti instance that polls many servers. I have a different analytic platform where I need to get the data to this platfrom from cacti. Has anybody done something like this? Is it possible to retrieve cacti data remotely via web service calls or anything?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the rrdtool dump data. Find where cacti stores the rrd files.  Usually something like /var/lib/cacti/rra or /usr/share/cacti/rra

For each graph there should be a graph_name.rrd.  Use rrdtool dump command to convert these into XML files which can be parsed and sent to your other program?

```
rrdtool dump graph_name.rrd
```

Answer (score 0):

Please verify that the correct datasource is created as well as there is no mistakes when creating the graph template. You can also use a debug function at the top of the graph that tells you if it found the rd database or not.